# What is the cardinality of $\Bbb{N^N}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

What is the cardinality of $\Bbb{N^N}$?

my answer: $|\mathbb{R}|$ $=$$|2^\mathbb{N}|$ $\leqslant$ $|\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}|$ $\leqslant$ $|\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}|$ $=$ $|(2^\mathbb{N})^\mathbb{N}|$ $=$ $|2^{\mathbb{N}\times\ \mathbb{N}}|$ $=$ $|2^\mathbb{N}|$ $=$ $|\mathbb{R}|$

In the end $|\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}|$ $=$ $|\mathbb{R}|$

Is that okay?

Comment: Yes, except that the third item from the end should be $\left|2^{\Bbb N\times\Bbb N}\right|$.

Comment: Yes, but i didn't know \times\. Thank you

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The answer is fine.

(Incidentally my students just have this question in their homework)

Comment: Maybe he is your student ;)

Comment: I doubt that, we gave a slightly different formulation.

Comment: I was kidding, though I guess you gave your homework in Hebrew so the different formulation can be a result of translation

Comment: Oh, it was more than that. It was different mathematically :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct, though I would of added that you know that
for cardinals $k\leq l,l\leq k\,\implies k=l$